# Landscape and portrait image sizes within css

Tags: wordpress, css, woocommerce

What would the best CSS be to display my category images so they are not squashed or display distorted.

The images themselves are 1024 x 768 and even with the Wordpress/Woocommerce settings being set at 400 x 400 for the thumbnail and then after regeneration of the thumbnails there are still the same:

[Live Link](http://dev.jzm.co.nz/dr/dermarollerau/shop/)

I can change the CSS but not the HTML.

**CSS:**

```
ul.products li.product .img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

  ul.products li.product img {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: try adding `height:inherit` in `ul.products li.product img `

Comment: I changed the `height:` to `max-height:` which appeared to fix the aspect ratio problem, though then they are not centered, but that may be easier to address.

Comment: i didn't noticed the live link. sorry. i'll go for Marc Audet's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible fix might be:

```
ul.products li.product img {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will work with the portrait style thumbnails, but not sure about landscape style.

What you want here is to have the thumbnails fit in the 150x150 box regardless of the aspect ratio of the thumbnail image.

On line 534 of woocommerce.css, the following declaration:

```
ul.products li.product img {
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

I would simply remove the height/width values or set them to auto.  This would allow the images to scale to fit the parent container.

Wordpress is also using media queries, so the CSS is setting the width/height on the img in more than one place.  For example, see the style near line 1968:

```
ul.products li.product img {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: What would be the best way to enlarge the landscape images but also keep the li class so the rest of the data is aligned?

Comment: Keep the `.img-wrap` as is because that defines the parent container for your image, a square box, which is okay.

Comment: I have for now but since its set to 150x150 its showing the border half way up the image but if I remove it I need to do the above

Comment: You need to check the media query section of the style sheet, see updated answer.

Comment: Done but note the overlapping of the img of the img wrap and ive changed them all http://d.pr/i/MPhC

Comment: Adding a max-width and max-height seems to fix the problem.  I think we covered all the cases...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you allready solved the ratio problem but I see that at least one of the images is flowing out of the container. To fix this extend your **img-wrap** class with **overflow:hidden**

```css
class="img-wrap" {
  ...
  overflow:hidden;
  ...
}
```

**And never use width=100; on the img tag!** This will blow the image up and be blury like hell - that prevents it from looking professional. 
I suggest also to display the image centered. To do this I use the display:table-cell; trick and then set the margin left and right to auto. The new css for you:

```css
ul.products li.product img {
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0;
  ---width: 100%; /*<- remove this line to unblury your image*/
  background-position: center;
  display: table-cell; /* display trick to enable centering by margin*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Which is what `overflow: hidden` was designed to do... not always appropriate.